# How to use array object in for loop using angular 11?

Tags: angular

I have fetched data from backend API, need to loop the data in front end but its value not return.

here is my response from backend API.

```
[
    [
        {
            "choice": 1,
            "count": 4,
            "percentageValue": "80.0000"
        },
        {
            "choice": 2,
            "count": 1,
            "percentageValue": "20.0000"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "choice": 1,
            "count": 4,
            "percentageValue": "80.0000"
        },
        {
            "choice": 2,
            "count": 1,
            "percentageValue": "20.0000"
        }
    ]
]
```

In ts file

```
submitPoll(data){
    this.pollService.submitPoll(data).subscribe(response =>{
      this.percentage=response.body;
    });
  }
```

In html file

```
<p *ngFor="let percentage of percentage;let i= index;">
                  {{percentage.choice  }}
                </p>
```

how to use the for loop for array object ? i need to display the percentage in options

Comment: It's an array of an array. You either need to flatten the inner arrays to one level up or use two nested `*ngFor`s in the template.

Comment: can you send the answer for above object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ng-template ngFor let-percentItems [ngForOf]="percentage">
    <ng-template ngFor let-items [ngForOf]="percentItems">
        {{ items.choice}} | {{ items.count}} | {{ items.percentageValue}} |<br />
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: its actually return only first two rows

Comment: how to fetch only first array only

Comment: this.pollService.submitPoll(data).subscribe(response =>{
      this.percentage=response.body;
      this.percentage = this.percentage.slice(0, 1);
    });

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelD mentioned, `percentage` is array of array. A simple solution is to use `*ngFor` twice.

```
<div *ngFor="let innerArray of percentage;">
  <p *ngFor="let obj of innerArray;">
    {{obj.choice}}
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming response.body is a valid json array as specified you could just use the following to grab the inner items and merge them into a new array for use

```
const percentages = [].concat(...response.body);
```

You will then end up with the following for use in your loop

```
[
  {
    "choice": 1,
    "count": 4,
    "percentageValue": "80.0000"
  },
  {
    "choice": 2,
    "count": 1,
    "percentageValue": "20.0000"
  },
  {
    "choice": 1,
    "count": 4,
    "percentageValue": "80.0000"
  },
  {
    "choice": 2,
    "count": 1,
    "percentageValue": "20.0000"
  }
]
```